# Evaluate all pair combinations of rows of two tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to define a custom op in tensorflow, in which at one point I need to construct a matrix (`z`) that would contain sums of all combinations of pairs of rows of two matrices (`x` and `y`). In general, the numbers of rows of `x` and `y` are dynamical.

In numpy it's fairly simple:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

rows_x = 4
rows_y = 2
dim = 2

x = np.arange(dim*rows_x).reshape(rows_x, dim)
y = np.arange(dim*rows_y).reshape(rows_y, dim)

print('x:\n{},\ny:\n{}\n'.format(x, y))

z = np.zeros((rows_x*rows_y, dim))
print('for loop:')
for i, (x_id, y_id) in enumerate(product(range(rows_x), range(rows_y))):
    print('row {}: {} + {}'.format(i, x[x_id, ], y[y_id, ]))
    z[i, ] = x[x_id, ] + y[y_id, ]

print('\nz:\n{}'.format(z))
```

returns:

```
x:
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]],
y:
[[0 1]
 [2 3]]

for loop:
row 0: [0 1] + [0 1]
row 1: [0 1] + [2 3]
row 2: [2 3] + [0 1]
row 3: [2 3] + [2 3]
row 4: [4 5] + [0 1]
row 5: [4 5] + [2 3]
row 6: [6 7] + [0 1]
row 7: [6 7] + [2 3]

z:
[[  0.   2.]
 [  2.   4.]
 [  2.   4.]
 [  4.   6.]
 [  4.   6.]
 [  6.   8.]
 [  6.   8.]
 [  8.  10.]]
```

However, I haven't got a clue how to implement anything similar in tensorflow.

I was mainly going through SO and the tensorflow API in hopes of finding a function that would yield combinations of elements of two tensors, or a function that would give permutations of elements of a tensor, but to no avail.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could simply use the broadcasting ability of tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3],[4, 5],[6, 7]], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3]], dtype=tf.float32)

x_ = tf.expand_dims(x, 0)
y_ = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)
z = tf.reshape(tf.add(x_, y_), [-1, 2])
# or more succinctly 
z = tf.reshape(x[None] + y[:, None], [-1, 2])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(z)
```

Comment: It's magic... So, to get this right: you're first expanding `x` and `y`, so that `x_` has shape [1, 4, 2], and `y_` has shape [3, 1, 2]. And then, the broadcasting ability of `tf.add` "figures out" how to fill out the dimensions into [3, 4, 2] (which is the shape of `tf.add(x_, y_)`), and finally, `tf.reshape` ensures that we have 2 columns in `z`. The "figuring out" is the key part, and as I'm reading [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting): ...

Comment: ... "When two compatible arrays are encountered, the result shape has the maximum among the two inputs at every dimension index.", and then: "A special case arises, and is also supported, where each of the input arrays has a degenerate dimension at a different index. In this case, the result is an "outer operation". That's subtle. Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Defining `z` as variable and updating its rows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from itertools import product


x = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3],[4, 5],[6, 7]],dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3]],dtype=tf.float32)

rows_x,dim=x.get_shape()
rows_y=y.get_shape()[0]

z=tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros([rows_x*rows_y,dim]),dtype=tf.float32)
for i, (x_id, y_id) in enumerate(product(range(rows_x), range(rows_y))):
    z=tf.scatter_update(z,i,x[x_id]+y[y_id])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    z_val=sess.run(z)
    print(z_val)
```

This prints

```
[[  0.   2.]
 [  2.   4.]
 [  2.   4.]
 [  4.   6.]
 [  4.   6.]
 [  6.   8.]
 [  6.   8.]
 [  8.  10.]]
```

**Option 2**

Creating `z` throw list comprehension:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from itertools import product


x = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3],[4, 5],[6, 7]],dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.constant([[0, 1],[2, 3]],dtype=tf.float32)

rows_x,dim=x.get_shape().as_list()
rows_y=y.get_shape().as_list()[0]


z=[x[x_id]+y[y_id] for x_id in range(rows_x) for y_id in range(rows_y)]
z=tf.reshape(z,(rows_x*rows_y,dim))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    z_val=sess.run(z)
    print(z_val)
```

**Comparison**: The second solution is around two times faster (only measuring the construction of `z` in both solutions). In particular, the timings are: 
first solution: 0.211 seconds, second solution:0.137 seconds.

Comment: Construction time is usually an invalid metric of performance, since it happens only once; no one cares about a difference of <1s start-up time. I'd be much more interested in knowing if there was any inference time performance difference.