# Define loss function in keras using itertools

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-itertools, loss-function

I want to define a loss function, which represent the distance between the hidden layer output points. Firstly ,I wrote this without keras

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
pts = np.array([
    [10,10,10],
    [10,11,20],
    [20,11,30],
    [20,10,10],
    [10,10,20],
    ])
diff = list(itertools.combinations(pts, 2))

ptdiff = lambda (p1,p2): (np.sqrt(np.sum((p1 - p2) ** 2)))
diffs = map(ptdiff, diff)
np.mean(diffs)
```

I get the result. And I try this loss function in keras, `z` is the output of hidden layer, which is a matrix

## define loss function

```
def vae_loss(z):
    z_diff = list(itertools.combinations(z,2))
    ptdiff = lambda (p1,p2): (np.sqrt(np.sum((p1 - p2) ** 2)))
    z_diffs = map(ptdiff, z_diff)
    loss = K.mean(z_diffs)
    return loss
```

But it shows the `TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable.`, I just wonder how can I fix this problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to use this loss function? Did you consider using for example the entropy as a measure of dissimilarity between the rows of your matrix? Does the scaling matter for your application?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to use this loss function to make the data points at feature space as near as possible. I want to measure the dissimilarity between each two rows of my matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43534057/evaluate-all-pair-combinations-of-rows-of-two-tensors-in-tensorflow) very helpful question, you can make use of Keras' broadcasting properties. I'm assuming here you run Keras on the TensorFlow backend. From the TF [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/broadcasting) on broadcasting:

> A special case arises, and is also supported, where each of the input
>   arrays has a degenerate dimension at a different index. In this case,
>   the result is an "outer operation".

A reproducible example of your numpy code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

# Generate 100 random points in a 5-D space
n_dim = 5
matrix = np.random.rand(1000, 5)

# List all possible combinations
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(matrix.tolist(), 2))

def mse(tup):
    """MSE between first and second element of a tuple of lists"""
    return np.mean((np.array(tup[0]) - np.array(tup[1]))**2)

avg_mse = np.mean([mse(c) for c in combinations])
print('Average mse: {:.3f}'.format(avg_mse))
```

This returns, in my case, `Average mse: 0.162`

Based on the question cited above, you could construct your loss function as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K

# Wrap our random matrix into a tensor
tensor = K.constant(value=matrix)

def loss_function(x):
    x_ = K.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0)
    x__ = K.expand_dims(tensor, axis=1)

    # Compute mse for all combinations, making use of broadcasting
    z = K.mean(K.square(x_ - x__), axis=-1)

    # Return average mse
    return(K.mean(z))

with K.get_session() as sess:
    print('Average mse: {:.3f}'.format(loss_function(tensor).eval()))
```

Which returns for me `Average mse: 0.162`.

Note that this implementation does not *exactly* replicate the behaviour from your numpy example. The difference is that all combinations of rows with itself are also considered (not the case with `itertools.combinations`) and combinations are considered twice: `mse((row1, row2))` and `mse((row2, row1))` will both be calculated, which is again not the case with your `itertools` code. For matrices with a large number of rows, this should not make too much of a difference, as my example shows.